# How to hide .svn directories in Windows explorer?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-explorer

I am using TotoiseSVN on Windows Vista which works very well. Only one thing keeps bothering me: Under Vista the explorer expands the .svn subdirs and that is very confusing.

- Is there a way to generally hide all .svn-Folders in Explorer?
- Perhaps something to put into the Registry?

(Yes, I can make my Explorer ignore all hidden files, but that is no possible solution, because I need to see them for other reasons during development)

Thank you!

Comment: Hiding hidden files is the only way I know of.

Comment: Another option is not using Explorer for anything serious. ;)  Also, there is a shell extension (http://students.kennesaw.edu/~rzillige/shell/HiddenFilesToggle.html) that adds a context menu item to toggle hidden files visibility.

Answer (score 4):

1. From command prompt, first make the .svn unhidden 
   --> attrib -h .svn /s /d
2. Then make all the .svn folders system folders + hidden 
   --> attrib +h +s .svn /s /d

This way you can still show your hidden files/folders (like I do) but as long as you have "Hide protected operating systems files" checked, the .svn folders won't show up in windows explorer.

Comment: I wonder why the .svn folder doesn't have the +s attribute by default. By design a user (or even an admin) shouldn't be poking around in it.

Answer (score 3):

wait until Svn 1.7 which will do away with them in favour of a single file held outside the folder tree.

Otherwise, apart from going golfing with Bill, you'll have to turn the show hidden files option off.

Comment: I think it will be a single `.svn` at the root of (but still inside) your working copy, like for git and mercurial.

Comment: I#m not sure - never asked, but its possible it'll be a file in your home directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to look at using a WindowsExplorer *alternative*.

For example, I use **DirectoryOpus** - http://nudel.dopus.com/opus9/

It has an option in Preferences to toggle *Show in Folder Tree | Hidden Folders* - 
which I believe is what you're referring to when you say that you still **want to see it but not expanded** - which I take to mean, **not in the left-hand (tree) view**.

This screenshot illustrates what I get (and what I think you're after)

In my case, the folder is *.git* (not *.svn*), but they are the same for our purposes. They are folders automatically marked as hidden.

(This software does many, many more things - such that I can no longer even use WindowsExplorer).

[image]

Comment: In Opus you can also set up wildcard filters globally (hide .svn everywhere) or for specific folders/branches (hide .svn in my source area) if you don't want all hidden-attribute items to be hidden. Unlike the options mentioned in the answer, the wildcard filters I mention only affect the file display and not the tree currently, but global filters are planned for the future. (Disclaimer: I help write plugins and bits of Opus and I wrote the guide/intro linked in this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a windows explorer window and search for every thing *.svn
2. Select All in the results window and make these guys invisible, by right clicking and changing the properties
3. Change Windows to not show hidden files

   OR
4. To not view.svn files in the explorer TREE and File System, open up a command prompt, navigate to your repository folder and type "attrib +h *.svn /s"  You will still have to make windows make hidden files invisible though.